# Merge two map objects and return custom objects javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, merge, find

I have two arrays

```
let a1 = [{id: 1, name: "terror"}, {id: 2, name: "comics"}, {id: 3, name: "suspense"}]
let a2 = [{id: 1, name: "terror"}, {id: 3, name: "suspense"}]
```

I need to compare these arrays against each other and come out with something like this:
    [{id: 1, name: "terror", selected: true}, {id: 2, name: "comics", selected: false}, {id: 3, name: "suspense", selected: true}]

I tried using `filter` below, but it didn't work, what should I do?

```
a2.filter(data => {
  return a1.find(value => {
    let x = data.id === value.id ? {
      id: value.id,
      text: value.name,
      selected: true
    } : {
      id: data.id,
      text: data.name,
      selected: false
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `filter` because you need an output array that has the same number of items you started with - use `map` instead, to create a new array which has the same number of elements as the original array, only transformed.

Since it looks like `a2` doesn't have any new information, and is only useful by showing the *existence* or *abscence* of some objects, a method with low complexity would be to `map` `a2` to a `Set` of `id`s, and then generate the new objects by iterating over `a1` and checking whether their `id`s are in the `Set`:

```js
let a1 = [{id: 1, name: "terror"}, {id: 2, name: "comics"}, {id: 3, name: "suspense"}]
let a2 = [{id: 1, name: "terror"}, {id: 3, name: "suspense"}]
const a2IDs = new Set(a2.map(({ id }) => id));
const output = a1.map((item) => ({ ...item, selected: a2IDs.has(item.id) }));
console.log(output);
```

It would be possible to fix up your code so that it works, changing `.filter` to `.map` and using `.find` as you are, but it'll have greater complexity because it'll have to iterate over items in `a2` each time (`Set` lookups by comparison are `O(1)`).

Comment: what's mean this sintaxis and thank you by your answer.

{ (this: "...item" ), (this not: "selected: a2IDs.has(item.id)") }
do you have any docs that i can read?

Comment: What is sintaxis?

Comment: "...item", is to iterate o something?

Comment: That's object spread: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax